# Should I use Subversion?

Tags: svn

Some friends and I are planning to create software which is not open-source. It is commercial software (we need authentication), and we need to work in different locations and at different times (not in sync).

One person cannot replace the job of another person.

In this case should I use Subversion?

I tried, but I can't understand Subversion. I would like something with checkout and checkin functionality to a server repository.

I have access to just one SSH account (I have read about Git, but by this issue I couldn't use it).

Comment: Even if you worked alone, on a single computer, in a single location, you should use a VCS. What don't you understand in Subversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are writing software, even if you're working alone, you need to be using version control. The question should never be "should I use it?", it's "which one will I use?"

Whether it's svn, git, mercurial, TFS, Perforce or any of the other systems out there, you need to be using *something*. People will say that centralized VCSs (like svn) are dinosaurs and that one should only use a DVCS (git, mercurial). It's almost a religious war. As long as you're using a reliable, proven VCS, you're on the right track.